# How to create a Zend_Db_Table model

Tags: zend-framework, model

Hy Guys,

I have a small problem and i haven't been able to fix it. So, i have this table, called epg_live_channels, and i need to create a Db Table model.
I've typed: zf create db-table EpgLiveChannels epg_live_channels, and i get this error: A models directory was not found.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not using modules right? You are using this command in your project folder ?

Full Command:

```
 zf create db-table name actual-table-name module force-overwrite
```

Comment: can u tell me a solution for this when am using modules.  Am not getting the model inside the module folder

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but when you built this application you probably did not build it with Zend_Tool (you didn't use the command line to build the project). what is probably happening is that the *.zfproject.xml* file has entry for your directory structure or does not exist (or just got corrupted somehow).
 If this sounds familiar you should be able to fix this by creating a blank project and then just copying over the *.zfproject.xml* to your existing project.